# Invalid key hash after build to apk and how to solve this for many device?

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I have built a "Log In with Facebook" button for my app, it's working normally in the virtual device, but after I built my app to apk and test it on the real device, there is a problem "Invalid key hash. The key hash lULhSMXXXXXXXXXX does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXX.
Then I go to developers.facebook.com/apps/XXXXXXX and add the key hash lULhSMXXXXXXXXXXXX to setting and it worked normally. So I have a question, if I install my app in many different devices, how can I make the "Log In with Facebook" button working without have to add a key hash for each device like this. Thank you. This is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    loginFacebook(loginResult);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });

private void loginFacebook(final LoginResult loginResult) {
    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                    String userId = null;
                    String name = null;
                    try {
                        userId = object.getString("id");
                        name = object.getString("name");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    Log.d("Shreks Fragment onSuccess", "" + profile);

                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, Intent.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                    finish();
                }
            });
    request.executeAsync();

}
```

Comment: I think there are usually 2 key hashes, one for development and another for release. Have you added both of them here and followed the following steps : [Setting a Release Key Hash](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash) ? When you installed on the device did you sign the apk already or was it still debug version?

Comment: Yes, I clicked on quick start and added two key hashes, and when I build to apk file with Android Studio I choose build type is release, but it still not working. When I install my app on real device, it still notify the key hash is not stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to add total three key hashes at Facebook developer.

1.using package manager in android app.

```
  try {
                PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
                for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                    md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                    String sign = Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                    Log.e("MY KEY HASH:", sign);
                    //textInstructionsOrLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textstring);
                    //textInstructionsOrLink.setText(sign);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sign, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d("nope", "nope");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            }
```

2.Debug key using command line

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64
```

3.Release key using command line

```
keytool -exportcert -alias app_alias -keystore C:\Users\usename\app_keysrore.jks | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64
```

please add this all key hashes and check again.

**Note** :

1. You have to generate all these keys on the same machine which is
   used to sign an APK using key store.
2. We have to add two debug key hashes because key produced by package
   manager and command line are different.

Comment: I tried your solution, but there are two key hashes are the same.

Comment: @  Goo Ae : Had u put both on facebook developer ..?? Please provide screenshot of error.

Comment: This is my screenshot. When I build and run my app on my mobile phone, I had this problem https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipO5VkfVIEsucstQW7Ps-kgrKDw9EsKW2BspkVY5CKpUXWVfM9_gOF3XxMVKf344zQ/photo/AF1QipPpDpVwXiWZ_1S5N4OWuaqo2SIHOc4dJiVql1mf?key=MGpLZjVxdlVIQXE5aXZsSXlWNTZGTUI3UUV6TVZR