# How many key hash entries can be added in facebook app for android?

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I've got a Facebook app "*abcd*". I've done integration with my Android app "*pqrs*". My question is while adding key hash is there any limit? If yes then how many key hashes can be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add as many as key hashes for Facebook.

Please check this answer by me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32174717/4018207

Note : Please add all key hashes for every machine you developed app. Because keyhash should be generated from same machine as on which release apk is builded.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should have 2 for each facebook app.

1. For development. (obtained from default keystore)
2. For production. (obtained from you production keystore)

If you have different development environments. You should consider creating Test apps for each environment under your main facebook app (which is your production app).

You can have multiple development key hashes but only one production key hash.

Note : Test apps should only have development key hashes