# Facebook Login - Invalid Key Hash. The key hash xxx...x does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-4.0, parsefacebookutils

I am trying to add Facebook Login to my Android app (using Parse) with the code below.

```
List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
            ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this,  permissions, new LogInCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                    if (user == null) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                    } else if (user.isNew()) {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                    }
                }
            });
```

When the code above is executed, the following screen appears:

[image]

These are the things I have tried (already went through many threads on SO):

1. Already entered the debug and release hashkey in the [Facebook Apps Page](http://developers.facebook.com/apps/) by getting it running the `keytool` utility: 
   [image]
2. I used the [right openssl version](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/list) from here as per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20506658/android-facebook-sdk-key-hash-does-not-match-any-stored-key-hashes-when-uploadi) and [this](https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/60).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Check this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/32174717/4018207..And also copy hash key you are getting on facebook page and update it to your application stored on facebook developer..!!

Comment: @AndiGeeky Yep, that was it. DIdn't think all three needed to be done, though it's mentioned i read it now. Amazing how bad facebook's documentation is here.

Comment: That answer is about how many key hashes should be added to facebook.. I am adding solution to your question here..!!

Comment: You duplicated this anyway..!!

Comment: Sorry, thought that was appropriate. Thank you though - can I un-duplicate this?